# How to submit data from Contact form on React JS application to Formstack?

Tags: reactjs, formstack

I am trying to receive my contact form data from Reactjs application to formstack.

Comment: you can **POST** form data to _formstack_ using `axios`

Comment: check this out: https://www.formstack.com/blog/2012/embed-an-iframe/

Comment: @Rishabh Mishra - could you please send me a link?

Comment: Thanks Sour LeangChhean. it helped.